# PHP to PDF - Use text from XML document to create PDF?

Tags: php, pdf

I have some xml files that contain text, which are displayed on my website. I want to extract the text from these xml files and convert them to a pdf document that users can download.

1. how can I can extract this text from the xml documents? (libraries etc?)
2. how can I use this text to create a pdf document?

I am working in a PHP environment, however if this is not the suitable language, I could change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to parse an XML file, and many ways to output a PDF file.

I suggest you start with the XML functions within PHP `http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php`

There are also various classes to write PDF files, try googleing for them.